# SQL query to return frequent itemsets like Python example

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql

**Question**

I would like to use a SQL query to return the top 5 frequent itemsets containing a given tag (string).

In my Python example below (only included to show what I am trying to achieve with SQL) I used the [Apriori](http://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/frequent_patterns/apriori/) algorithm but I would also be happy to see any simpler alternative approaches using Postgres if this is hard to implement.

**Data**

I have the following tables in my PostgreSQL:

```
table tag (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  label TEXT UNIQUE
);

table article_tag (
article_id INT REFERENCES article(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
tag_id INT REFERENCES tag(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE ,
PRIMARY KEY (article_id, tag_id)
);

  CREATE table article (
 id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
title TEXT);
```

- tags are programming languages or technologies
- author is the author of an article
- article_tag is a map of articles to tags

I have just started to use Postgres SQL and would like to replicate what I have done with this data using Python.

Python code:

```
import pandas as pd
from mlxtend.preprocessing import TransactionEncoder
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import apriori

tags = """1 python
    2   azure-devops
    3   lua"""

tagrows = [i.split() for i in tags.splitlines()]
df_tags = pd.DataFrame(tagrows,columns = ["id","label"])
df_tags["id"] = df_tags["id"].astype(int)
df_tags.set_index(df_tags.id,inplace=True)

article_map = """1  1
2   1
1   2
3   2"""

article_map = [i.split() for i in article_map.splitlines()]
df_article_map = pd.DataFrame(article_map,columns=["article_id","tag_id"])
df_article_map["tag_id"] = df_article_map["tag_id"].astype(int)
df_article_map["article_id"] = df_article_map["article_id"].astype(int)
df_article_map.set_index(df_article_map.tag_id,inplace=True)

merged = df_tags.merge(df_article_map,left_index=True, right_index=True)
merged_group = merged.groupby('article_id').label.apply(list).reset_index()
merged_group.set_index("article_id").sort_index()
tag_list_of_lists = merged_group.label.values.tolist()

te = TransactionEncoder()
te_ary = te.fit(tag_list_of_lists).transform(tag_list_of_lists)
df = pd.DataFrame(te_ary, columns=te.columns_)
frequent_itemsets = apriori(df, min_support=0.02, use_colnames=True)
frequent_itemsets['length'] = frequent_itemsets['itemsets'].apply(lambda x: len(x))
frequent_itemsets
```

This allows me to find frequent itemsets in the dataframe with length > 1.  (I have only added a minimal, reproducible example here so we don't get many frequent itemsets).

```
string_hit = 'python'

frequent_itemsets[(frequent_itemsets.itemsets.apply(lambda x : string_hit in x) & (frequent_itemsets.length > 1) & (frequent_itemsets.support > 0.03))]
```

Output:

[image: output]

**What have I tried:**

This is my first attempt with SQL to query for this data.  It does not return the desired output and I'm unsure how to proceed.

```
 SELECT article.id, article.title,
    article_tag.tag_id ,tag.label
   FROM article,
    article_tag,tag
  WHERE (article.id = article_tag.article_id AND article_tag.tag_id = tag.id  )
 GROUP BY article.id,article_tag.tag_id,tag.label
  order by id
```

Comment: Can you expand on two things: (1) what is lacking in the Python code that prompts you to write it in SQL, and (2) what problems you are having with giving it a go in SQL?

Comment: @halfer 1.  If I need to use Python I will but I was hoping that PostgreSQL would be well suited to this kind of task.  2.  I added my initial attempt.

Comment: OK. Could you prepare a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)? That allows you to create some example tables, add some example data, and run a query. If you can also show in your question how the output varies from your desired output, that would also be helpful. I think this question is not getting answers because it is too broad.